# Parsing header of file

Tags: c++

I am working with images. I would like to extract width and height of it from a header.

The width is represented at location

```
  size
   4B   width
   4B   height
```

they are represented at specific index.

I tried parse it and extract it with code

```
    ifstream f(name, ios::binary | ios:: in ); // reading a file in binary
    ostringstream ob;

    if ( f.fail()){   // fail test
        return false;
    }

     f.seekg (0, f.end);
     int length = f.tellg();   // length of the file
     memory = new char[length]; // allocate array of chars
     f.read (memory, length);  // read the content of the file into an array
     f.seekg (0, f.beg);    // point back at the beginning of the file.
```

Each of them has 4B , so using for loop

```
for ( int i = index ; i <4 ;i++){
     cout << hex<< memory[i];
}
```

or i even tried it converting it into number using

```
   string a;
   for ( int i = index; i < 4 ;i++{
       a+=memory[i];
   }
   cout <<  atoi( a.c_str() )   << endl;
```

Should output a number , but it output some unreadable format.

Comment: What is `index`? Do you mean `for ( int i = index ; i <index + 4 ;i++)`?

Comment: Never use `new type[count]`, use `vector<type>` instead. Anyhow, you will have to extract a minimal example for your question to conform to site rules. ATM it is off-topic.

Comment: Do you have a link to the format of the header? Is it the first two values that are the height and width? Does the documentation tell you what "endian" is used to store the numbers?

Comment: image is stored in .raw format , offset 4 and 4B is width , offset 8 and 4B is height

Comment: Do you know how the image was written out? Do you have any documentation about the format at all?

Answer (score 4):

You're seeking to the beginning of the file *after* reading it, rather than before. You need to switch round the `read()` and the `seekg()`:

```
f.seekg (0, f.beg);    // point back at the beginning of the file.
f.read (memory, length);  // read the content of the file into an array
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't give very much information to go on so a little guesswork here but this is how I might approach reading the file:

The main features being, don't use manual memory allocation, use a `std::vector` (its what its for). Also copy the data from the *char array* into variables cast from the correct type. This ensures alignment is correct (never cast into the *char array*). Another approach might be to read directly from the file into the correctly typed variables cast into `char*`.

```
int main(int, char* argv[])
{
    // first parameter needs to be file name
    std::string name = argv[1] ? argv[1]:"";

    std::ifstream ifs(name, std::ios::binary|std::ios::ate); // open at end

    if(!ifs)
    {
        std::cerr << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    if(ifs.tellg() < 8) // too small
    {
        std::cerr << "Bad image file, too short" << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Don't allocate memory manually, use a container
    std::vector<char> image(ifs.tellg()); // big enough for whole file

    ifs.seekg(0); // back to beginning

    if(!ifs.read(image.data(), image.size()))
    {
        std::cerr << std::strerror(errno) << '\n';
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // copy raw data into variables

    std::uint32_t width;  // 4 bytes wide integer
    std::uint32_t height; // 4 bytes wide integer

    std::copy(&image[4], &image[ 8], (char*)&width);  // offset 4 bytes
    std::copy(&image[8], &image[12], (char*)&height); // offset 8 bytes

    // at this point a lot depends on the system architecture and
    // how the number is stored in the file. The documentation
    // should tell you if it is little-endian or big-endian

    // you may have to do manual jiggery-pokery
    // to change endienness

    std::cout << "width : " << width << '\n';
    std::cout << "height: " << height << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For a quick answer of the problem stated in the title, and by looking at the input file you specify, you could simply read three lines, skip the first and then extract one integer each from the following two lines.

So something like

```
int width, height;

std::string input;
std::istringstream is;

std::getline(stream, input);  // One line for the "size" string

std::getline(stream, input);  // One line for the width
is.str(input)
is >> width;

std::getline(stream, input);  // One line for the height
is.str(input)
is >> height;
```

If you have multiple entries like this in the file, then do the above in a loop.

If the file doesn't actually contain the texts you show, just the numbers, then it's even simpler:

```
int width, height;
stream >> width >> height;
```

Or if you have multiple entries

```
while (stream >> width >> height) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::cout` will print data passed as characters if the data is `char`, so try casting before printing.

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
     cout << hex<< (int)(unsigned char)memory[index + i];
}
```

If the number in the file is little endian, it can be converted to integer like this:

```
// Use #include <cstdint> for using type uint32_t and uint8_t
uint32_t num = 0; // the converted number will be here
for ( int i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++) {
    num |= (uint8_t)memory[index + i] << (uint32_t)(8 * i);
}
```